# okular default printer settings

Tags: kubuntu, printing, kde, okular

In Kubuntu 11.10, Okular does not seem to obey the CUPS default printer settings. So everytime I want to print something double-sided I have to select the option in Okular, really inconvenient. Is this a known bug? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a KDE/Qt bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdegraphics/+bug/425297
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176999
- http://bugs.kde.org/180051

Shortly ( http://bugs.kde.org/180051 ):

> Description From Nicos Gollan  2009-01-08 19:02:22
>
> There needs to be some way to have persistent printer settings. From
>   looking around on the web, it seems like:
>
> - KDE 4 wants to use whatever Qt provides
> - Qt does not seem to provide any useful printer settings tools

There are patches but you need to compile the Qt-libs to use them. Or use non-KDE programs ( Comment #17 From C W J Lemmens  2009-11-20 11:44:47 ):

> For our non-KDE programs (firefox, openoffice and some older stuff)
>   I found a perfect replacement for "kprinter" : gtklp !! Take a look
>   here : it solved more than half of my problems :
>   http://gtklp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For others: At the bottom of this link: http://bugs.kde.org/180051 there is a PPA with a patch for QT that fixes this. It worked for me.